# Is it possible to group SharedPreferences in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

In Native Android, we can specify a file name for the SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

another one like

```
SharedPreferences pref2 = getSharedPreferences(SAMPLE_2, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This way we can group values per file and possible to use same key for different shared files.
Is this possible with this [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) flutter package or not?